# How to put the 0s at the end of my multidimensional arrays in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

How do i put 0's at the end of my multidimensional array. My array is a 4x5 sized.

These are my values

```
4 23 1  0  9
0 6  0  77 9
0 23 0  0  66
0 38 65 2
```

Expected outcome:

```
4  23  1   9   6
77 9   23  66  38
65 2   0   0   0
0  0   0   0   0
```

I tried it with this code. I tried to move the non zero arrays to a new multi dimensional arrays then fill the rest with zero but I kept getting out of bounds error.

```
static void MoveZero(int[,] arrayNum)
{
    int newArrayIndex = 0;  
    int newArrayIndex1 = 0;
    int[,] newarrayNum=new int[4,5];
    for (var outer = 0; outer < 4; outer++)
    {
        if(newArrayIndex1>=6){
                newArrayIndex1=0;
            }

        if(newArrayIndex>=5){
                newArrayIndex=0;
            }

        for (var inner = 0; inner < 5; inner++)
        {
            if(arrayNum[outer,inner]==0){
                continue;
            }

            newarrayNum[newArrayIndex,newArrayIndex1] = arrayNum[outer,inner]; 
            newArrayIndex++;
            
        }
        newArrayIndex1++;
        
    }

    Display(newarrayNum);
}
```

Comment: For the OutOfBounds Exception. Where do you get it? When you know where it should be easy to understand the why. Has arrayNum the same setup in dimensions?

Comment: @Ralf i think its because of the newarrayindex overlapping the original [4,5] size

Comment: What is the purpose of `MoveZero()` and why does not only accept a matrix for an argument and nothing else? From the info given it seems you are attempting to create a `Resize()` function that changes the number of rows and columns and leaves the unspecified elements as zero. If this is correct, please [edit] your post and make it clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Some observations and comments about your code:

1. You (and anyone who reads your code) benefit from simple, but descriptive variable names. This also helps for debugging your code; especially when visually/manually debugging it.
2. You are using the values `4` and `5` multiple times in `MoveZero()`
3. `MoveZero()` doesn't know the size (row count and column count) of the input array`, but in your code, it is assumed that the size is known
4. The indices used in your new array are checked for every single iteration of in your original array. Seeing as the indices for your new array have nothing to do with the indices of your original array, this may be confusing and cause noise when interpreting the logic in the code.

##### Suggestions for how to change your code with respect to these comments:

1. **Introduce simple and descriptive variable names**

   - `arrayNum` --> `array`. Reasoning: Both you and your code know that the input array contain numbers (`int`s), seeing as it is of type `int[,]`. Furthermore, there are no arrays in `MoveZero()` of other types (i.e. you don't need to differentiate between an array of ints and an array of strings). Keep it simple when possible.
   - `outer` --> `rowIndex`/`row`. Reasoning: It's easier to visualize how your array is iterated through (i.e. which cell is being checked at any moment in your code) when the variables describe the dimensions of the array. `row` and `col` are relatable words.
   - `inner` --> `colIndex`/`col`. Reasoning: Same as for `outer`.
   - `newarrayNum` --> `newArray`. Reasoning: same as for `arrayNum`.
   - `newArrayIndex` --> `newRowIndex`/`newRow`. Reasoning: Same as for `outer`.
   - `newArrayIndex1` --> `newColIndex`/`newCol`. Reasoning: Same as for `outer`.
2. **Create variables for *magic values***

   - Why are `4` and `5` being used? What do they mean? It is clear when we have the context of your example input array / your description of your input array having 4 rows and 5 columns. For any person who only sees `MoveZero()` and does *not* have this context, though, it is *not* clear/implicit.
   - Define `int rowCount = 4;` and `int colCount = 5;` and replace the use of `4` and `5` where appropriate.
3. **Make no assumption of array size**

   - All `MoveZero()` knows about the input array is that its type is `int[,]`. Whether the size is `2x3` or `134x896`, it doesn't know; hence, no size assumptions should be made. *Calculate* the row count and column count from the input array, rather than assuming them to be `4` and `5`.
   - For a two-dimensional array, you can find the number of rows by checking the length of the 0th array dimension (`arrayNum.GetLength(0)`) and the number of columns by checking the length of the 1st array dimension (`arrayNum.GetLength(1)`).
   - The implementation of `rowCount` and `colCount` made in the previous step should hence be adjusted. Row count and column count should not be static numbers.
4. **Do validity checks where appropriate**

   - Verifying that the indices used in the new array are *valid* indices is only necessary to do at the time when they are being used. Indices for the new array are only being used at the time of populating the new array; i.e. in the inner for loop, after checking if the item in the original array is equal to `0`.

Implementing these changes, your method now may look like the following:

```csharp
static void MoveZero(int[,] array)
{
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int cols = array.GetLength(1);
    
    int newRow = 0;  
    int newCol = 0;
    
    int[,] newArray = new int[rows, cols];
    
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            if (array[row, col] == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (newCol > cols)
            {
                newCol = 0;
            }

            if (newRow > rows)
            {
                newRow = 0;
            }

            newArray[newRow, newCol] = array[row, col]; 
            newRow++; // updating new row index
        }
        
        newCol++; // updating new col index
    }

    Display(newArray);
}
```

Now, you may notice a couple of things:

1. The *new row index* is incremented everytime you have populated a cell in your new array. An incrementation of the *new row index* means you move downwards in the same column. Hence, you are populating your new array *column by column*, even though you are traversing your original array *row by row*. As far as I have understood your question, you do want to populate your new array *row by row*.
2. The *new column index* is incremented everytime you move to the next row in your original array (i.e. directly before a new iteration of your outer `for` loop). Seeing as you don't know where there are `0` values in your input array, you cannot assume that a change of row/col indices will happen simultaneously for the original and new array, at any point in your code.

By adding a `Console.WriteLine()` directly before the population of the new array,

```
Console.WriteLine($"newArray[{newRow}, {newCol}] = array[{row}, {col}] = {array[row, col]}");

newArray[newRow, newCol] = array[row, col];
```

I get the following console output:

> newArray[0, 0] = array[0, 0] = 4
> newArray[1, 0] = array[0, 1] = 23
> newArray[2, 0] = array[0, 2] = 1
> newArray[3, 0] = array[0, 4] = 9
> newArray[4, 1] = array[1, 1] = 6
> Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Considering the quick incrementation of the new row index, I'd say that's what generates the out of bounds error.

An example fiddle of the new implementation (including the console output) is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kqWL3h). Hopefully it can be helpful for solving the issues.

---

##### A suggestion for how the code could be modified to make it work

1. Update the `newCol` value directly after you have used it to populate `newArray` (i.e., directly after `newArray[newRow, newCol] = array[row, col];`). But: rather than unconditionally *incrementing* the `newCol` value (i.e. doing `newCol++`), *update the value to the next valid column value*. We can achieve this by using the [modulo](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic) operator as follows:
   `newCol = (newCol + 1) % cols;`

   - In your example, valid column values are 0--4 (seeing as the total column count is 5). This means that when `newCol == 4` and we want the value to be updated, we want to set `newCol = 0` rather than `newCol = 5`. In the modulo operation, `newCol + 1` is the *dividend* and the total column count is the *modulus*. The result from the modulo operation, i.e. the *remainder* from the division operation `(newCol + 1) / cols`, is the appropriate new value for `newCol`.
2. Update the `newRow` value directly after you have updated the `newCol` value; but *only* if `newCol == 0` (i.e. only if we went from the rightmost column to the leftmost column).
3. After implementing these two changes, there is no longer need for checking the validity of the `newCol` and `newRow` values; these checks can be removed.

The resulting implementation of `MoveZero()` may look as follows:

```csharp
static void MoveZero(int[,] array)
{
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int cols = array.GetLength(1);
    
    int[,] newArray = new int[rows, cols];
    
    int newRow = 0;  
    int newCol = 0;
    
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            if (array[row, col] == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            newArray[newRow, newCol] = array[row, col];
            
            newCol = (newCol + 1) % cols;
            
            if (newCol == 0)
            {
                newRow++;
            }
        }
    }

    Display(newArray);
}
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/irx74r).

Comment: @honkhonk I have a suggestion for how you could modify your code to make it work. Let me know if you want me to include it.

Comment: the code is now working but i would like to know how you would approach it

Comment: thank you also for the very informative information

Comment: @honkhonk Glad to help! I have updated my answer with a final section with a suggested approach.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

1. Create the same empty new array.
2. Scan your array.
3. If you encounter non-zero value while scanning then copy it to the new array.
4. Right after copying the value increment the indices for the new array.

**Example**

Given initial array is

```
int[,] array = new int[,]
{
    { 4, 23, 1,  0,  9},
    { 0, 6,  0,  77, 9},
    { 0, 23, 0,  0,  66 },
    { 0, 38, 65, 2,0 }
};
```

The code would be

```
int[,] array2 = new int[4, 5];
int i2 = 0;
int j2 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if (array[i, j] != 0)
        {
            array2[i2, j2] = array[i, j];
            j2++;
            if (j2 > 4)
            {
                j2 = 0;
                i2++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Comment on your code**

Your general approach is correct. It is visible from your code that you are scanning the array, and whenever you encounter non-zero value you are copying it to new array. So you are following the steps 1, 2 and 3 given above. But you are incrementing your indices, for the new array, at wrong place. `newArrayIndex1` in outer loop and `newArrayIndex` in inner loop. And the right moment to do that is after copying the value to the new array.

So, illogical building of your algorithm (not following step 4) eventually led you to an error which you got already.

Comment: it works now, but can you explain to me why my code does not work?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I was delayed. In fact, your approach is correct. At least it is visible from your code. You are scanning the array, and whenever you encounter non-zero value you are copying it to new array. That's fine. What I find not correct is that you are incrementing your indices, for the new array, at wrong place.

Comment: Logically it should be right after copying the value to the new array. So the steps should be -> 1) Scan the array, if 2) Encounter non-zero value then 3) copy the value 4) right after this increment the indices. In your code one of the indices you are incrementing in outer loop and the second one in inner loop. This doesn’t make a sense. So, illogical building of your algorithm eventually led you to an error. This is my explanation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mat1_1d = new int[] {
         4, 23,  1,  0,  9,
         0,  6,  0, 77,  9,
         0, 23,  0,  0, 66,
         0, 38, 65,  2};

    var mat2_2d = Resize(mat1_1d, 4, 5);
    Display(mat2_2d);
    //4   23    1    0    9
    //0    6    0   77    9
    //0   23    0    0   66
    //0   38   65    2    0
    Console.WriteLine();
    
    var mat3_2d = Pack(mat2_2d);
    Display(mat3_2d);
    // 4   23    1    9    6
    //77    9   23   66   38
    //65    2    0    0    0
    // 0    0    0    0    0
}
```

with the functions `Resize()`, `Pack()` and `Display()` defined below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Packs the specified matrix. This moves all zeros to the end
/// of the matrix.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="matrix">The input matrix.</param>
/// <returns>A packed matrix of the same size.</returns>
static T[,] Pack<T>(T[,] matrix)
{
    int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    int columns = matrix.GetLength(1);
    // Create a flat array from the matrix for sorting
    T[] flat = new T[matrix.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(matrix, 0, flat, 0, Buffer.ByteLength(matrix));
    // Generate a sequence of keys in ascending order
    var keys = Enumerable.Range(1, matrix.Length).ToArray();
    // Modify key sequence to replace 0's with a large number
    keys = keys.Zip(flat, (num, x) => !x.Equals(0) ? num : matrix.Length+1).ToArray();
    // Sort values based on keys
    Array.Sort(keys, flat);
    // Convert back to 2D matrix
    T[,] result = new T[rows, columns];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(flat, 0, result, 0, Buffer.ByteLength(matrix));
    return result;
}
```

with the helper function to generate a 2D matrix from an array

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert an array into a 2D matrix
/// </summary>
/// <param name="array">The input array.</param>
/// <param name="rows">The number rows requested.</param>
/// <param name="columns">The number of columns requested.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
static T[,] Resize<T>(T[] array, int rows, int columns)
{
    int length = Math.Max(array.Length, rows * columns);
    var flat = new T[length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, flat, 0, Buffer.ByteLength(array));
    T[,] result = new T[rows, columns];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(flat, 0, result, 0, Buffer.ByteLength(array));
    return result;
}
```

This draws to console a matrix using fixed columns

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays the specified matrix in fixed columns of width 4.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="matrix">The matrix to display.</param>
static void Display<T>(T[,] matrix)
{
    int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    int columns = matrix.GetLength(1);

    const int width = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j],width} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```